# The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework, installation

I am installing Sitecore 9.0 update 1 using SIF version 1.2.1 , have installed Solr 6.6.2 also by following http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/install-sitecore-9-update-1-4-simple-steps/ blog
but i am getting this below error while running Install-Stecore.ps1

[image]

Below are the things which i tried but none of them worked:

1.increased post delay to 25000 in xconnect-solr.json file
[image]

2. Increased retry count to 20 in InvokeManageSolrCoreTask file

[image]

3. Have installed SOLR in D drive
4. Have imported the solr-ssl.keystore by double clicking on the file

Can anyone please help what might be the issue.

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you visit https://localhost:8986/solr in a browser?

Comment: I'm guessing the cert isn't trusted. If you look at the Solr script from the link you provided (the PowerShell script), you can see how it manipulates Solr. The script edits a few files to set up the SSL connection. Go through and verify that the steps completed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify your TLS connection. It is blocked while executing the script. Add this line to your script:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = ([Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12)
```

Comment: can you please specify where do i need to add this line in the script, whether this line needs to be added in the solr script or while installing sitecore instance script. Please check this blog "http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/install-sitecore-9-update-1-4-simple-steps/" once and please suggest where  have to add this line .

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `SolrUrl` in both JSON files for `Sitecore` and `Solr`. Please note that the Solr url with https should be something like `https://{solrHost}:{solrPortNumber}` based on the URL you followed to configure `https` for `Solr`.

Please update the files and try once more.